# How to annotate types in abstract base classes in python with mypy

Tags: python, types, mypy, typechecking

I would like to use mypy to check python codebase.

I am having two problems when it comes to annotating AbstractBaseClasses with mypy:

1. How to disable `NotImplemented? not callable` errors when using:

```
class AbstractClass(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def get_something(self) -> List[str]:
        raise NotImplemented(f'You need to implement `get_something`!')
```

The motivation here is that I would like to explicitly raise Exceptions when someone didn't implement the method.

2. How to have some pre-defined behaviour included in any class inherited from AbstractBaseClasses, and keep the signature intact?
   I would like to keep the `-> CustomClass` signature for the sake of the interface

```
class AnotherABC(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def info(self) -> CustomClass:
        self.logger.info('Info called')
        pass  # Cannot create CustomClass here -> not enough information
```

Comment: The exception you want to raise is called `NotImplementedError`. `NotImplemented` is a special value used for other purposes

Answer (score 0):

Finally decided to:

1. Remove the explicit exceptions, and put docstrings instead

```
    @abstractmethod
    def get_something(self) -> List[str]:
        """some small description"""
```

2. Remove the logging from abstract base classes and moved it to the children classes. Technically it could be done also with a wrapper